# Как обновить датагрид?

Tags: c#, datagrid

Облазил кучу форумов. Каждый пишет свой метод.

В общем делаю биндиг к базе через контакты `BindingSource`. Хотел после занесения данных обновить грид таким способом

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
  dataGridView1.DataSource = контактыBindingSource;
```

Answer (score 1):

`dataGridView1.DataBind()` не забыли?

Comment: Хм.. А можно чуть поконкретнее)?

Comment: @Radzhab, после того, как вы задали DataSource для GridView, вам нужно сделать Привязку данных из источника к элементу управления GridView. [Пример][1]
[1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx

Comment: Я делал привязку через форму

Answer (score 0):

Пример для Access, для удобства вынес в отдельную функцию

```
void RefreshDataGrid ()
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"data source=" + Application.StartupPath + @"\baza.mdb";
    conn.Open();
    string sSQL = "select * from Таблица1";
    OleDbDataAdapter myAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sSQL, conn);
    //создаем и заполняем DataSet
    DataSet myDS = new DataSet("MyDataSet");
    try
    {
        myAdapter.Fill(myDS, "Таблица1");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //обрабатываем ошибку
        Console.WriteLine("Error! " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally //так или иначе, но мы должны закрыть соединение
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

    //закончив изменения с DataSet, отправим изменения на сервер:
    myAdapter.Update(myDS, "Таблица1");
    dataGrid1.SetDataBinding(myDS, "Таблица1");
}
```

Comment: хм... SetDataBinding у меня нет ..